# What is a good implementation of a peer-to-peer chat program with a server for assigning connections in C++?

Tags: c++, client-server, implementation, chat, p2p

For a while, I've been interested in creating a proof-of-concept chat program using C++. I have given the idea a lot of thought and even wrote down the beginnings of how I would design the system, but I have hit a barrier in my thinking when it comes to the implementation.

I want to know what an implementation of a peer-to-peer chat client with a server to route connections would look like in C++.

The server would be used as a central registry of the peers, but not used as the primary connection. The server would not interact with the clients in any way except to assign connections between peers to achieve an optimal path between peers. In a first version, it would merely be a directory to which all clients connect, and the clients can then use the directory to connect to the other clients available for chat. (I hope that explains it a bit more). :)

Comment: Please make clear what you want to server to do. I does make much sense to me at the moment.

Comment: Are you saying, "Show me an actual implementation of a chat program written in C++?".

Comment: I would have to volunteer that the solution to this is way too complex to post on here, there's simply not enough scope for the amount of detail!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) stuff. It is all about routing and co-ordinating messaging. It uses de-centralization and a peer-to-peer like architecture.

There are also plenty of open source implementations. For example,

- [Jabber.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabber.org)

Comment: Thanks!

This should get me started on the implementation to see some examples of similar designs.

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: No worries. There is plenty of source to have a ganders at. Also look at Pidgin and libpurple. You could base your software on that!

Comment: Don't forget to re-share your source code if you build something off open-source software ;)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really think at something better than the chat example in 
the Boost.Asio documentation. Search for the examples documentation in Boost.Asio.

Comment: Thanks for the additional leads.